# How to install Qt Core?

Tags: c++, qt

For example, I need QString class in my project, but I don't want to install the whole 3 GB+ Qt package to be able to use it. Qt's online installer contains a lot of checkboxes, among which I can't find the right one. I have Windows with MinGW already installed, so I also don't need one Qt suggests. So how to get the bare minimum without all the redundant stuff?

[image: Qt Installer]
[image: Qt Installer]

UPD: added the screenshots of the installer and changed the name of the question, so it better represents my problem

Comment: No, You can not. The Qt classes are interrelated so it is difficult to extract the dependencies of a class. The minimum that can be done is to install the base module (in your case "core") and its dependent modules (in your case there are no dependencies)

Comment: QString is part of QtCore, which in itself is already 5.5 MB on my system. My advice would be not to use Qt at all if you just want a string class; learn to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Have a look into the doc. [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) is part of the Qt core. So, this is the package you need definitely. (I believe it doesn't have further dependencies.)

Comment: @Thomas You must admit that `QString` provides some additional features compared to `std::string` (although OP could have mentioned why he specifically wants `QString`).

Comment: @Scheff Absolutely, QString is far nicer to work with. But it's not worth depending on Qt just for that.

Comment: @Thomas In which installer is it distributed? Are there two versions of them for commercial and open-source use? Whichever I've got doesn't have ```core``` option https://imgur.com/5ZxtO7f

Comment: QtCore is the core library that everything else in Qt depends on. You can't _not_ install it, as far as I know.

Comment: @Thomas So how can I use it? O_o And if I need to install something else to be able to use the core library, what would it be?

Comment: There is a distinct gap in C++ where QString fits. We could definitely use a platform independent unicode string built into the language.